# std::iterator using a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector

I have a large vector and I have divided it into smaller pieces using pointers that point to small sections of that pointer. Now, I want to use std::iterator to iterate through the section marked by the pointer of the large vector.

`imgVec is that large vector`

```
// dividing the imgVec into pieces of size queue_len
for (int i=0; i<imgVec.size(); i += queue_len) {
                    buff = &imgVec[i];
                    imgPtr.push_back (buff);
}
```

initially the iterator code was like this:

```
for (folly::fbvector<InputImage>::iterator it = imgVec.begin(); \
                        it != imgVec.end() ; ++it) {
    folly::via (&cpuThreadPoolExecutor, \
        std::bind(vcu::follyPerformDetection, *it.base(), detectConfig));
}
```

Now, I need the iterator to begin with the `imgPtr[0]` pointer pointing towards the beginning and the `imgPtr[1]` pointing towards end of a section of the queue. How do I put that into the iterator?

Comment: Why are you using pointers to mark boundaries, if you plan to then use iterators to navigate between boundaries? Use pointers throughout, or iterators throughout; it doesn't make sense to mix and match. But, if you absolutely insist: `auto iter = imgVec.begin() + (yourPtr - &imgVec[0]);`

Comment: How does this work? I mean if I put this line instead of just imgVec.begin(), what does it do?

Comment: It produces an iterator pointing to the same element that `yourPtr` points to. Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: This seems like a very exceptional use case. Are you sure you can't just use a vector of pointers to InputImage objects assigned on the heap? i.e. `std::vector< std::unique_ptr<InputImage> >`